# MongoDB index: totalDocsExamined returns 0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have coded a MongoDB index using the Mongo Java driver as follows:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");

DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("indexdemo");

coll.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("code",1));

for (int ii=0;ii<100000;ii++) {

DBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("code", ii);

coll.insert(doc);

}
```

When I execute an explain plan of the index (MongoDB 3.x), the index bounds seems to be recognized however totalKeysExamined is 0 and totalDocsExamined is 0 as well

```
db.indextest.find({code: 5000}).explain("executionStats")
{  
. . . .
   "executionStats":{  
      "executionSuccess":true,
      "nReturned":0,
      "executionTimeMillis":0,
      "totalKeysExamined":0,
      "totalDocsExamined":0,
      "executionStages":{  
         "stage":"FETCH",
         "nReturned":0,
         "executionTimeMillisEstimate":0,
         "works":1,
         "advanced":0,
         "needTime":0,
         "needFetch":0,
         "saveState":0,
         "restoreState":0,
         "isEOF":1,
         "invalidates":0,
         "docsExamined":0,
         "alreadyHasObj":0,
         "inputStage":{  
            "stage":"IXSCAN",
            "nReturned":0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate":0,
            "works":1,
            "advanced":0,
            "needTime":0,
            "needFetch":0,
            "saveState":0,
            "restoreState":0,
            "isEOF":1,
            "invalidates":0,
            "keyPattern":{  
               "code":1
            },
            "indexName":"userid_1",
            "isMultiKey":false,
            "direction":"forward",
            "indexBounds":{  
               "code":[  
                  "[\"1111\", \"1111\"]"
               ]
            },
            "keysExamined":0,
            "dupsTested":0,
            "dupsDropped":0,
            "seenInvalidated":0,
            "matchTested":0
         }
      },
      "allPlansExecution":[  

      ]
   },
```

Answer (score 1):

When you will have exactly one match by index, you will defenitely get totalKeysExamined=1 and totalDocsExamined=1.

- Check if you use correct collection: db.getCollection("**indexdemo**")
  vs db.**indextest**.find()
- Make sure db.indextest.find({code: 5000}) returns 1 document. By now you have nReturned=0.
- Check index name: usually if you create index {code: 1} it will be named code_1 and your stats shows "indexName":"userid_1"